# With fixed number of functions, how can I calculate the size of a Bloom Filter given the probability of false positives?

Tags: c, algorithm

I need to implement a bloom filter. And I cannot find a way out of this.

With fixed number of functions, how can I calculate size of a Bloom Filter given the probability of false positives ?

For example, I want that the filter have 10% of false positives, I have the number functions and the number of elements in the set.

How can I calculate the size of Bloom Filter that match the false positive probability ?

Answer (score 2):

The formula for this is on the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).  Assuming you have enough hash functions available, you need ~4.8 bits per element given the false positive rate you specified of 0.1.

In this case it looks like 4 hash functions would be optimal.  Note that more hash functions isn't always better -- if there are very many hash functions relative to the size of the filter, you quickly set almost all the bits on, and you get lots of false positives.

Comment: I should add that in practice you should check your hash functions to verify they are well-behaved on real world input.  Writing good hash functions is non trivial.