# Bloom Filter: evaluating false positive rate

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, probability, bloom-filter

Given a fixed number of bits (eg. slot) (m) and a fixed number of hash function (k), how one compute the theoretical false positive rate (p) ?

According to Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter, for a false positive rate (p) and a number of item (n), the number of bits (m) needed is given by `m = - n * l(p) / (l(2)^2)`  and the optimal number of hash function (k) is given by `k = m / n * l(2)`.

From the formula given in Wikipedia page, I guess I could evaluate the theoretical false positive rate (p) by the following: `p = (1 - e(-(k * n/m)))^k`

But Wikipedia has another formula for (p) : `p = e(-m/n*(l(2)^2))` which, I suppose, assume that (k) is the optimal number of hash function.

For my example, I took `n = 1000000` and `m = n * 2`, the optimal value for (k) would be 1.386, and the theoretical false positive rate (p) would be 0.382 according the previous formula.
Let's choose the number of function, compute the theoretical false positive rate (p) given a fixed (k) and compute the theoretical number of bits needed (m'):

```
for k = 1, p = .393 and m' = 1941401
for k = 2, p = .399 and m' = 1909344
for k = 3, p = .469 and m' = 1576527
for k = 4, p = .559 and m' = 1210636
```

The more bits are stuffed in the filter, the more false positive we get. Seems logical.

**But could one confirm that formula `p = (1 - e(-(k * n/m)))^k` is correct to get the theoretical false positive rate given a fixed (k),(m) and (n) ?**

Note: the question seems already asked here: [With fixed number of functions, how can I calculate the size of a Bloom Filter given the probability of false positives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556432/with-fixed-number-of-functions-how-can-i-calculate-the-size-of-a-bloom-filter-g) but there's no answer that match my exact question.
[How many hash functions does my bloom filter need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658439/how-many-hash-functions-does-my-bloom-filter-need) might be of interest, but again it's not exactly the same.

Regards

Comment: Could you please state a clear question? AFAICT you've answered your own questions by reading the Wikipedia page, so it's not particularly clear what you're looking for at Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Kaganar I rewrote a bit the question and put emphasis on the important real question. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: The Wikipedia article is fairly explicit (and correct) up until the last step where it introduces the exponential function. At that point it uses an approximation I'm not familiar with. Are the steps before the exponential function throwing you off?

Comment: @Kaganar On the page I read p = (1 - e(-(m/n*l(2)) * n/m)) ^ (m/n * l(2)) before simplication as l(p) = - m/n * l(2)^2. I took the first formula and replace m/n*l(2) by k, but I'm sure about my reasoning to be correct.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not following what you're trying to ask. The answer to your posted question is: Yes, the formula is correct. You seem to be trying to resolve an inconsistency you're perceiving with that formula and a result of using related formulas, but I'm not catching what the relation you're finding is. I'm not sure which 'first formula' you're substituting into, and thus I may be missing the issue.

Comment: use separate bitmap for the each hash function so that will reduce the false positive rate dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
m – number of elements in bit array
n – number of items in collection
p – false positive probability  // 0.0 – 1.0
^ – power

p = e^(-(m/n) * (ln(2)^2));
```

I wrote a math-friendly tutorial on Bloom Filters:
https://web.archive.org/web/20141011213433/http://techeffigy.wordpress.com/2014/06/05/bloom-filter-tutorial/

Comment: Link is now dead